# Retrieving ECS tags using boto3

Tags: python, boto3

I have below boto3 which gives `list of dicts with key, value pairs`.

```
service_paginator = ecs_client.get_paginator('list_services')
for page in service_paginator.paginate(cluster=cluster_name,
                                       launchType='FARGATE'):
    # print(page)
    for service in page['serviceArns']:
        response = ecs_client.list_tags_for_resource(resourceArn=service)['tags']
```

This dict has multiple keys, value pairs. in the below sample format:

```
Row-1:[{'key': 'Platform', 'value': 'XX'}, {'key': 'StackVersion', 'value': '1.0.1'},{'key': 'ResourceOwner', 'value': 'TeamA'}, {'key': 'Stackname', 'value': 'myfargate-1'}, {'key': 'Service', 'value': 'Processing'}, {'key': 'Name', 'value': 'someName'},{'key': 'deploy_date', 'value': '2021-07-12'}, {'key': 'Source', 'value': 'somesource'}]
Row-2:[{'key': 'Platform', 'value': 'XX'}, {'key': 'StackVersion', 'value': '1.0.1'},{'key': 'ResourceOwner', 'value': 'TeamA'}, {'key': 'Stackname', 'value': 'myfargate-1'}, {'key': 'Service', 'value': 'Processing'}, {'key': 'Name', 'value': 'someName'},{'key': 'deploy_date', 'value': '2021-07-12'}]
Row-3:[{'key': 'Platform', 'value': 'XXY'}, {'key': 'StackVersion', 'value': '1.0.1'},{'key': 'ResourceOwner', 'value': 'TeamA'}, {'key': 'Stackname', 'value': 'myfargate-1'}, {'key': 'Service', 'value': 'Processing'}, {'key': 'Name', 'value': 'someName'},{'key': 'deploy_date', 'value': '2021-07-12'}, {'key': 'Source', 'value': 'somesource'}]
```

From this lists, I would like to print the service, where in the dict `'key' == 'Platform' and 'key' == 'Source'`  present. So output should be Row-1 and Row-3 , as ROw-2 doesn't have key called `source`.
for one key it's ok, but if I have to check multiple keys then it gives me ZERO count.

Is there any pythonic way to do it for more than one key?

Answer (score 1):

I will answer this to myself, but I personally don't like this solution, if anyone has any better solution, please post it here.

```
service_paginator = ecs_client.get_paginator('list_services')
for page in service_paginator.paginate(cluster=cluster_name,
                                       launchType='FARGATE'):
    # print(page)
    for service in page['serviceArns']:
        response = ecs_client.list_tags_for_resource(resourceArn=service)['tags']
        tags = {}
        for item in response:
            tags[item['key']] = item['value']

            if 'Platform' in tags and 'Source' in tags:
                platform_name.append(tags['Platform'])

print(set(platform_name)) # to print the unique platform_name
```